# How to format database query using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 5 variables which i need to format as query and send to server for further processing.I am trying to do it through jQuery and its working fine but the real challenge for me is that sometimes those variables contain empty values.In that case i have to remove that part from the query .
                 My concern is that how to remove that part of the query containing empty values and send the correct query..
Any help will be hearty appreciated.Thank you.

```
var query;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#go").click(function () {
        var datefrom=$("#fromdate").val();
        var dateto=$("#todate").val();
        var extension= $("#extension").val();
        var authcode=$("#authcode").val();
        var wwid=$("#wwid").val();

        query = "'"+ datefrom +"'" + " and " + " '" + dateto + "'" + " and ";
        alert(query);

        $("#gridId").GridUnload();
        gridload();
    });
});
```

Comment: You should reconsider doing this on server side. Because if you create a sql in the client and then send it to the server, somebody can easily modify your query to exploit your DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just chain them together

```
if(datefrom && datefrom.length > 0) {
  query += "'"+ datefrom +"'";
}

if(dateto && dateto.length > 0) {
  query += " and '" + dateto + "'";
}
```

and so on.

BTW: This should be done on the server side to validate what the user has given you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pieces = [];
if (datefrom.length) {
    pieces.push("datefrom = '" + datefrom + "'");
}
/* repeat above for other fields */
query = pieces.join(' and ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a fun trick like this:

```
query = "'" + [ datefrom, dateto ].join("' and '") + "'";
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvn2L/)